# pyusb no encuentra dispositivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de dectar todos los usb conectados a mi pc utilizando pyusb, pero se me presentan los siguientes problemas:

1.- no encuentra todos los dispositivos(no aparece un hdd conectado en el momento de la ejecución)

2.- como puedo obtener el iInterface(para dectectar el nombre del dispositivo) intente:

```
for cfg in dev:
  print(cfg[0]['iInterface'])
```

aqui esta el codigo completo

```
import sys
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)

for cfg in dev:
  sys.stdout.write('hex VendedorID='+hex(cfg.idVendor)+'& ProductId'+hex(cfg.idProduct)+'\n')
  print(cfg)
```

Y esto es lo que devuelve:

```
hex VendedorID=0x413c& ProductId0x8187
    DEVICE ID 413c:8187 on Bus 000 Address 001 =================
     bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
     bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
     bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
     bDeviceClass           :   0xe0 Wireless Controller
     bDeviceSubClass        :    0x1
     bDeviceProtocol        :    0x1
     bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
     idVendor               : 0x413c
     idProduct              : 0x8187
     bcdDevice              :  0x517 Device 5.17
     iManufacturer          :    0x1 Dell Computer Corp
     iProduct               :    0x2 DW375 Bluetooth Module
     iSerialNumber          :    0x3 E006E6DAC48E
     bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
      CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA ==================================
       bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
       bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
       wTotalLength         :   0xf4 (244 bytes)
       bNumInterfaces       :    0x4
       bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
       iConfiguration       :    0x0 
       bmAttributes         :   0xe0 Self Powered, Remote Wakeup
       bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)
        INTERFACE 0: Wireless Controller =======================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x3
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xe0 Wireless Controller
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN ==========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x10 (16 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x82: Bulk IN ===============================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x82 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1: Wireless Controller =======================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xe0 Wireless Controller
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x83: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :    0x0 (0 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x3: Isochronous OUT ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :    0x0 (0 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 1: Wireless Controller ====================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x1
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xe0 Wireless Controller
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x83: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :    0x9 (9 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x3: Isochronous OUT ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :    0x9 (9 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 2: Wireless Controller ====================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x2
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xe0 Wireless Controller
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x83: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x11 (17 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x3: Isochronous OUT ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x11 (17 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 3: Wireless Controller ====================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x3
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xe0 Wireless Controller
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x83: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x20 (32 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x3: Isochronous OUT ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x20 (32 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 4: Wireless Controller ====================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x4
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xe0 Wireless Controller
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x83: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x3: Isochronous OUT ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 5: Wireless Controller ====================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x5
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xe0 Wireless Controller
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x83: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x3: Isochronous OUT ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 2: Vendor Specific ===========================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x2
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
         bInterfaceSubClass :   0xff
         bInterfaceProtocol :   0xff
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x84: Bulk IN ===============================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x84 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x20 (32 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
          ENDPOINT 0x4: Bulk OUT ===============================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x4 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x20 (32 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 3: Application Specific ======================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x3
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x0
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xfe Application Specific
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x0 
    hex VendedorID=0xc45& ProductId0x6433
    DEVICE ID 0c45:6433 on Bus 000 Address 002 =================
     bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
     bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
     bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
     bDeviceClass           :   0xef Miscellaneous
     bDeviceSubClass        :    0x2
     bDeviceProtocol        :    0x1
     bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
     idVendor               : 0x0c45
     idProduct              : 0x6433
     bcdDevice              : 0x1315 Device 19.15
     iManufacturer          :    0x2 CN018T967248725GB6YMA01
     iProduct               :    0x1 Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD
     iSerialNumber          :    0x0 
     bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
      CONFIGURATION 1: 500 mA ==================================
       bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
       bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
       wTotalLength         :  0x37b (891 bytes)
       bNumInterfaces       :    0x2
       bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
       iConfiguration       :    0x0 
       bmAttributes         :   0x80 Bus Powered
       bMaxPower            :   0xfa (500 mA)
        INTERFACE 0: Video =====================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xe Video
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x5 Integrated Webcam
          ENDPOINT 0x83: Interrupt IN ==========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x10 (16 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x6
        INTERFACE 1: Video =====================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x0
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xe Video
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x5 Integrated Webcam
        INTERFACE 1, 1: Video ==================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x1
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xe Video
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x5 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x80 (128 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 2: Video ==================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x2
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xe Video
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x5 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :  0x100 (256 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 3: Video ==================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x3
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xe Video
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x5 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :  0x320 (800 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 4: Video ==================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x4
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xe Video
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x5 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   :  0xb20 (2848 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 5: Video ==================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x5
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xe Video
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x5 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   : 0x1320 (4896 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
        INTERFACE 1, 6: Video ==================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x6
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xe Video
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x0 
          ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x5 Isochronous
           wMaxPacketSize   : 0x1400 (5120 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x1
    hex VendedorID=0xa5c& ProductId0x5801
    DEVICE ID 0a5c:5801 on Bus 000 Address 003 =================
     bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
     bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
     bcdUSB                 :  0x110 USB 1.1
     bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
     bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
     bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
     bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
     idVendor               : 0x0a5c
     idProduct              : 0x5801
     bcdDevice              :  0x101 Device 1.01
     iManufacturer          :    0x1 Broadcom Corp
     iProduct               :    0x2 5880
     iSerialNumber          :    0x3 0123456789ABCD
     bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
      CONFIGURATION 0: 100 mA ==================================
       bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
       bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
       wTotalLength         :   0xab (171 bytes)
       bNumInterfaces       :    0x3
       bConfigurationValue  :    0x0
       iConfiguration       :    0x0 
       bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
       bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)
        INTERFACE 0: Application Specific ======================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x3
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xfe Application Specific
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x4 Broadcom USH w/swipe sensor
          ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x0
          ENDPOINT 0x1: Bulk OUT ===============================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x1 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x0
          ENDPOINT 0x85: Interrupt IN ==========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x85 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x10 (16 bytes)
           bInterval        :   0x20
        INTERFACE 1: Smart Card ================================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x3
         bInterfaceClass    :    0xb Smart Card
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x5 Contacted SmartCard
          ENDPOINT 0x82: Bulk IN ===============================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x82 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x0
          ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
           bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
           bInterval        :    0x0
          ENDPOINT 0x86: Interrupt IN ==========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x86 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x10 (16 bytes)
           bInterval        :   0x20
        INTERFACE 3: Application Specific ======================
         bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
         bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
         bInterfaceNumber   :    0x3
         bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
         bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
         bInterfaceClass    :   0xfe Application Specific
         bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
         bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
         iInterface         :    0x7 Broadcom USH
          ENDPOINT 0x87: Interrupt IN ==========================
           bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
           bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
           bEndpointAddress :   0x87 IN
           bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
           wMaxPacketSize   :   0x10 (16 bytes)
           bInterval        :   0x20
    [Finished in 0.5s]
```

este es el dispositivo que no detecta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que pyusb detecte a los dipsositivos externos al pc es necesario.
descargar la herramienta `libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0` para poder instalar el archivo `.info` correspondiente a cada dispositivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]